# Make batch file for install two or more software

Tags: security, batch-file, cmd, window, system

I want to create a batch file for installing two software jdk and mysql. I run batch file it install jdk and mysql server automatically.

Comment: Have you looked official doc ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: i don't want to use .net framework.

Comment: You could [run msiexec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372024(v=vs.85).aspx) in either `/quiet` or `/passive` mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both JDK and MySQL server have an option for a *silent* installation, where you can specify the options without using the graphical installer.

- JDK (example):`jdk.exe /s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature,SourceFeature,PublicjreFeature"`

  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html#jdk-silent-installation
- MySQL: `msiexec /i mysql-5.1.73.msi /quiet`
  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html#jdk-silent-installation

So, the *installation* shouldn't be a problem, as long as you already have the installation files.

Comment: i am trying to run these command on cmd but these are not working.

Comment: Your proposition _but these are not working_ has no diagnostic value. Some error messages might help more...

Comment: Since you did not provide any information I will venture a guess that you just copied the suggestions @Kurtibert posted as is. If the specified files did not reside in the current directory you would have to provide a full or relative path.